# filling in missing data in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this

```
pos value   
1 20
2 30
4 50
5 50
9 30
```

You will note that `3, 6,7,8` positions and respective value entries are missing. I would  like to fill them in with values corresponding to 0 so that the data looks like this

```
pos value   
1 20
2 30
3 0
4 50
5 50
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 30
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this in R?

Comment: A `merge` maybe ? `merge(data.frame(pos = min(df$pos):max(df$pos)), df, all.x = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   complete(pos = full_seq(pos, 1), fill = list(value=0))
# A tibble: 9 × 2
#     pos value
#   <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    20
#2     2    30
#3     3     0
#4     4    50
#5     5    50
#6     6     0
#7     7     0
#8     8     0
#9     9    30
```

If we want to continue until 20

```
df1 %>%
   complete(pos = full_seq(c(pos,20), 1), fill = list(value=0))
```

Comment: Very thankful! Can I give arguments for a start and stop? Say I want it to continue to pos 20, meaning positions with 10 to 20 will have values equal to 0?

Comment: @eastafri  Updated my post